# Creating a Web Application which supports multiple Backend

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql-server, database

I need to create a Web Based Database Application in Asp.Net and C# which will work across all database providers like SQL Server, MySQL etc. If client has SQL Server a small change in the program should make my web application work with SQL Server, If the client has MySQL it should also work with MySQL.

Is there is any tools available to do it ? or should I want to follow any Programming Procedures or methods to achieve it?

So Guide me to achieve the above scenario.

Comment: Look into MVC then there is a separation of concerns.

Comment: MVC would be a good choice but if you want to stick to Asp.net then you can use the Microsoft Enterprise Library which has generic db functions like the DBCommand, DBReader, DBAdapter etc. just pass the right database and use this generic libarary. I've used this in a project of mine which had both SQL and Oracle DB's

Comment: You're also going to want to avoid direct use of database queries in your application. You should use stored procedures so that the procedure names and parameters passed from the app are the same regardless of the database being used.

Comment: @Tim I would actually recommend NOT doing that, because sprocs are different between platforms. I'd use as plain vanilla ANSI SQL as you can in the data access layer so you don't have to port sproc code from backend to backend.

Answer (score 2):

To maintain independence of external systems (such as a database), you'll want to architect your solution to only speak to an interface.  You can then use several techniques, including dependency injection, to decide which implementation to use at runtime.

To keep it simple here, though, let's just use a factory.

First thing is to decide what your database should do.  Simple example - we'll store or retrieve an integer.  So first let's define that interface.  I'm leaving out async stuff for simplicity - but you'd really want that when talking to a DB.

```
public interface IDatabase{
    void Store(int value);
    int Get();
}
```

So now we've got something our calling code can use to refer to ANY type of database.

Next we'll need different types of classes for each DB

```
public class SqlServerDB : IDatabase{
    public void Store(int value){//store it}
    public void Get(){//get it}
}

public class MySqlDB : IDatabase{
    public void Store(int value){//store it}
    public void Get(){//get it}
}
```

Again, you DON'T want the calling code to know about implementation, so you can't instantiate the object with just a new.  Instead, you'll need to construct a class which knows about the different types of databases.

I'm using a string here, but you should use an enum in real code.

```
public static class DatabaseFactory{
     public static IDatabase GetDatabase(string dbName){
         switch(dbName){
             case "sqlserver":
                return new SqlServerDB();
             case "mysql":
                return new MySqlDB();
             default:
                 throw new ArgumentException("Don't know about that DB");
         }
     }
}
```

Now your calling code doesn't have to change with DBs.  If you've got a config object (like the built in .NET ones) you can change the database being used easily.

```
IDatabase myDB = DatabaseFactory.GetDatabase(Config.DBName);
myDB.Store(191);

int result = myDB.Get();
//result will equal 191!
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) which is a micro ORM for .Net. It supports sqlite, SQL Server CE, Firebird, Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQL Server.

Personally I have been really happy with using dapper and it's actually developed and used by Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Use SimpleData http://simplefx.org/simpledata/docs/ super easy to use and supports:
SQL Server 2005 and later
SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0
oracle
vistadb
mysql 4.0 and later
sqlite 3.0 and later
PostgreSQL
sqlanywhere
informix
Microsoft Access 2000, 2003, and 2007